# Having trouble with shell script result in applescript, in Automator

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, automator

I have a script that allows me to add tags to files only by right clicking on them. I select the tags and the script adds them automatically. They have a specific form: "&tag" and they are separated with white spaces.

What I'd like to do is to have an automator application, where a shell script searches for files by a certain criteria and that script passes the result to an applescript.

So my automator app starts with a "Run Shell Script" block and that's the only thing in it.

```
mdfind '(kMDItemContentTypeTree == "public.image" || kMDItemContentTypeTree == "public.video") && kMDItemFinderComment == "*&tag*"cd'
```

This returns a list of files with their POSIX paths.
Like this: {"/User/path1/file1","/User/path2/file2",etc.}

Then I have a "Run Applescript" box, where I'd like to access the files and their comments, but no matter how much I try, it does not work. I've tried using POSIX files, or accessing the comments from a "tell finder" block.. Nothing worked.

This is the simple most code, that I think should work just fine, but it doesn't!

```
on run {input, parameters}
  repeat with f in input
    display dialog (comment of f) as text
  end repeat
  return input
end run
```

Does anyone have any ideas what the problem might be? What am I missing?
Help me please!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder"
        repeat with i from 1 to number of items in input
            display dialog comment of (POSIX file (item i of input) as alias) as text
        end repeat
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

Comment: Then the result is:
Can’t make POSIX file (item 1 of {"/Users/...", "/Users/...", "/Users/...}) of application "Finder" into type alias.

Comment: Could it be the problem, that in the folder names, I have dots and | symbols..?

Comment: Try in Applescript editor, removing on run block, repeat loop and replacing f with a path of yours

Comment: I've edited the initial code to avoid the Finder confusion between items in list and items in folders, try it.

Comment: Thank You! With the new "repeat" cycle, everything works just fine! :)